# An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in PhoneApp2.DLL but was not handled in user code

Tags: windows

When using SQLite for windows phone app, I am getting error in sqlite.cs:

> path not for found

Here is the path, but when checked path could be found, I hardcoded the path and tried but it didn't work out.

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");
```

Here is the error

```
public static Result Open(string filename, out Sqlite3DatabaseHandle db, int flags, IntPtr zVfs)
        {

            return (Result)Sqlite3.sqlite3_open_v2(filename, out db, flags, "");
#else
            return (Result)Sqlite3.sqlite3_open_v2(filename, out db, flags, null);

        }
```

Here path db is coming `null`.